# MVC could not creates content and script files after adding view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have such problem, when I create MVC empty project and adding View from controller, it creates _Layout.cshtml file but could not creates content, script and font files, have any solution to fix it ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:
[image: img]

or

[this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio)